# Getting 400 Request Bad Error in RestTemplate code but getting Correct response in SOAPUI

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6, rest

Getting value exist error message in SOAPUI, but in spring restTemplate client code, I'm getting HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request.

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", authHeader);
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson, headers);
    System.out.println("" + entity);
    ResponseEntity<String> response=restTemplate.exchange(API_URL,HttpMethod.POST,entity,String.class);
```

But if I try a correct request in the above code, I'm getting success, if I try the same request again, I actually needs to get "Value Already Exist", but I'm getting 400 error

**Update**

Since it's an Error Scenario I'm getting Error Message in the Exception Body.
1 - So I need to catch the HttpClientErrorException
2 - use getBodyAsString() to get error message

Comment: most likely cause is a bad authorization header value for `authHeader`... but hard to say without more details. Perhaps the value of  `requestJson` is bad. If you provide more details in relation to these, what the equivalent SOAP UI request is (in curl form) I'd suspect you'd get a more useful answer.

Comment: You mentioned the response from SoapUI is "exist error message"? Is the response status code `400`?

Comment: status code is 400, but it displays "Value already exist", in SoapUI.

Comment: Thanks for the help @rob-evans, It got solved

Comment: pls post an update so others who see this post know what the solution was